# AsyncTask leaks: Robospice and AndroidAnnotations

Tags: java, android, android-annotations, robospice

As explained by many developers, the `AsyncTask` have an inconvenient: they induce leaks in some situations (for example, when the screen is rotated (and thus the activity restarted) during the `AsyncTask` execution).

I would like to avoid the use of `AsyncTask` and use either:

- RoboSpice : https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/wiki/Understand-the-basics-of-RoboSpice-in-30-seconds

OR:

- AndroidAnnotations : http://androidannotations.org/

Questions:

1. Is Robospice compatible with AndroidAnnotations? (if I start with Robospice and want to use AndroidAnnotations later)
2. Do the async methods in AndroidAnnotations have the same leaks as classical `AsyncTask` ?

Answer (score 1):

I actually use both libraries: RoboSpice for its service-based networking tasks and caching, and Android Annotations for getting rid of the boilerplate code, dependency injection and neatness. Recently I've written a blog post about combining the two in one app: http://blog.goyello.com/2014/06/26/androidannotations-robospice-the-best-of-both-worlds/. You'll find my sample on Github (https://github.com/ddekanski/SpiceAnnotations).

Answer (score 0):

1. Simplifying REST APIs is only a small part of AndroidAnnotations and is basically a wrapper  around Spring Android. If you don't plan to use that feature of AnroidAnnotations, it is fully compatible with RoboSpice.
2. If you do your REST calls from a @Background method of your activity, you'll have the same leaks as with an AsyncTask.